# Capture user input from Form

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner in PHP, I'm trying to add Google PR tool in my blog. but i don't know how to make a user input based PHP url.

```
<?
require("PRclass.php");
$url='http://www.digitcrop.com/'; 
$pr = new PR();
echo "$url has Google PageRank: ".$pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
?>
```

Exactly what I want.

> `$url='http://www.digitcrop.com/';`

Change to user input url with like below html

```
<p>
    <input name="url[]" type="text" id="url[]" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
</p>
<p>
    <input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to Submit the form( weather GET or POST Method ) and then Putting the Input Values on correct Locations.

```
<?php
require("PRclass.php");
if(isset($_POST['sample']))
{
    $url=urlencode($_POST['url']); 
    $pr = new PR();
    echo "$url has Google PageRank: ".$pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
}
?>
<form name="sampleform" method="post" action="">
<p>
    <input name="url" type="text" id="url" value="" size="80" /><br />
</p>
<p>
    <input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
</p>
<input type="submit" name="sample" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Form method you get it via $_GET['yourinput'] or $_POST['yourinput']

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @mfsymb's answer, you should put your input elements inside of a form element.  Set the following attributes within the form element tag:

```
    <form action='yourfile.php' method='post'>
```

Then, you can set your $url variable like so:

```
    $url=$_POST["url[]"];
```

Read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
require("PRclass.php");
if($_POST['sample']!="")
{
    $url=urlencode($_POST['url']); 
    $pr = new PR();
    echo "$url has Google PageRank: ".$pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
}
?>
<form name="sampleform" method="post" action="">
<p>
    <input name="url" type="text" id="url" value="" size="80" /><br />
</p>
<p>
    <input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
</p>
<input type="submit" name="sample" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: finally added a extra submit button, that really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use a named array for your input box (`name="url[]"`) since a textbox will be holding a single value only.

The second thing to make note of is that you will need a `<form>` tag in order to let PHP know that you're submitting some information to work with.

## HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>
    <input name="url" type="text" id="url" value="http://" size="80" /><br />
</p>
<p>
    <input name="findpr" type="submit" value="Find Google PageRank" />
</p>
</form>
```

`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` tells the form to post the data to the same page.

## PHP

```
// run the below code only if the form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['findpr'])) { 
  $url = $_POST['url']; // this is where we capture the user input
  // making sure the user enters a valid URL
  if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
  {
     echo 'The entered URL is not valid. Please try again';
  }
  else
  {
     require("PRclass.php"); 
     $pr = new PR();
     echo "$url has Google PageRank: ".$pr->get_google_pagerank($url) ;
  }
}
```